# Multiple If and Then Statements In The middle of Each other (Checkerboard using # and Spaces)

Tags: java

I am trying to create a checker board using spaces and the # key instead of the red and black squares. However I came across a problem with saying odd statements. I know how to say them...

For example:

if (num % 2 == 0) // this means the number is even

system.out.println()

else 
system.out.println()

However, I do not know how to state multiple statements in one go. For the checkerboard I am using rows and num. I have already defined them and this is my current code

```
public class Checkerboard {

    public Checkerboard() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // print board with 3 columns and 5 rows
        printCheckerboard(3,5);

        // print board with 4 columns and 3 rows
        printCheckerboard(4,3);

        // print board with 8 columns and 8 rows
        printCheckerboard(8,8);
    } 
     public static void printCheckerboard(int numRows , int numCols) 
    {
        // sample outer and inner for() loops
        // (assumes numRows and numCols are parameters
        // into the printCheckerboard() function)

        // for each row
        for (int row=0; row<numRows; row++)
        {

           // for each column in this row
           for (int col=0; col<numCols; col++)
           {
              // logic to print space or # goes here
               if (row % 2 == 0)   // If row is even
               {
                   if (col % 2 == 0)  //  And if column is even
                   {System.out.println ("#"); // Print a hashtag

                   }
                   else ();
                   if (row % 2 == 0) // If row is even
                   {if (col % 2 == 0) // And if column is also even
                   {System.out.println(" "); // Print a space


                   }
               }       
               }
               }

        }

    }

}
```

I am trying to say 
If the current row is even and column is odd, print a space
If the current row is odd and column is even, print a space
If the current row is odd  and column is odd, print "#"
However I only know how to say if the row and column is even, print a #
Please Help Me.

Comment: `else ();` what is that else with parenthesis ?

Comment: Well, basically you want to print the same thing if row and col are both even or odd or if they are different. In that case you could just do `if( row % 2 == col % 2)` which means they are either both even or both odd. Besides that, you should grab a tutorial on boolean logic and just go on the way you started it (nested if-else blocks). That's not very efficient but should suffice as a learning excercise. Then improve that with the boolean shortcut operators `&&` and `||` (e.g. if `(row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 0) || (row % 2 == 1 && col % 2 == 1)`) and finally you merge the conditions.

Comment: My bad, that was just some theory testing I was trying to do. Basically I had already established the even row and even column, but I was trying to say else if the even row and odd column

Comment: So Thomas, can i say if( row % 2 == 0 col % 2 != 0) does this mean row even and col odd?

Comment: You are missing an `&&`. Just do `if( row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 != 0)  { // print # }else{ //print space }`

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to check that `col` and `row` have the same parity:

```
public static void printCheckerboard(int numRows, int numCols) {
    // sample outer and inner for() loops
    // (assumes numRows and numCols are parameters
    // into the printCheckerboard() function)

    // for each row
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {

        // for each column in this row
        for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
            // logic to print space or # goes here
            if (row % 2 == col % 2) {
                System.out.print("#"); // Print a hashtag

            } else {
                System.out.print(" "); // Print a space
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```